# equivalent to perforce job in svn

Tags: svn, perforce

Is there an equivalent mechanism to a perforce job in svn, for grouping related changes?

Comment: use a bug tracking system, there are lots to choose from that intergrate well with svn.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least, not out of the box. That kind of revision metadata has to be stored elsewhere, like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), or some other system that's built on top of the SVN repository. I've not found another SCM that does this quite so nicely as Perforce, sadly.

Answer (score -1):

To group related changes, you'd use a [changelist](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/changelist-design.txt)

From what I've read about jobs, they're kind of like bug tracking references.

To associate a bug reference when committing, you'd have to implement something on top of SVN (as SVN doesn't have an integrated bugtracker), but you'd also have to say which bugtracker you did want to integrate with - and that means the technique will be different. In all cases, the bugtracker-association is performed in the post-commit hook.

For example, I use Mantis as my bugtracker, when I commit a change, if I've entered some magic words in the log message (eg "Fixed Bug #1234", or "Fixed Mantis #1234") then the post-commit hook will send that message and the extracted bug number to a Mantis URL using curl and automatically resolve the bug (and also add the log message text to the bugnote).

For a bugtracker, you can substitute any other API-driven system.

Comment: changelist support in SVN hasn't been implemented yet has it? Besides that, a Job in Perforce allows you to group changelists together!

Comment: fair enough, no-one said it was as fully-featured as Perforce's (though I'd question whether they are just more complicated), but svn changelists have been in since 1.5 : http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html